# How to set img dynamically

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am using sails.js. How would I set an Image src tag to a a string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var image = req.user[0].imageLink;
  console.log(image);
  if(!image){
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = image;
  }
</script>
```

I am getting image undefined.

Comment: What's `req` and `req.user`?

Comment: What are you getting in the `console.log`?

Comment: req.user is the sails.js part. I'm getting undefined

Comment: Are you not mixing server with client code?

Comment: @JY2k yes, req.user is server side, it's undefined because the front-end doesn't know that object exists. Do you want your view/front-end to be generated on the server (e.g. grab the the user and incorporate it via something like ejs) or do you want to make a request from your front end code (e.g. ajax request and then incorporate the result into the page?

Answer (score 0):

@JY2k since req is sent down to a view in locals you could also try...

in a sails view...